# Excel - How to count the number of times a value occurs consecutively once, twice, three

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of values (Up or Down) that I would like to count the number of times the values occur consecutively. For example;

```
Up
Down
Down
Up
Up
Down
Up
Down
Up
Up
Down
Down
Down
```

| Freq | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Up | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| Down | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Any ideas on how to accomplish this using an Excel function?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FREQUENCY with some Booleans to create arrays of row numbers of when and when they do not equal what you want.  Then we find how many times those bin counts equals the number we want with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(($A$1:$A$13=$E2)*ROW($A$1:$A$13),($A$1:$A$13<>$E2)*ROW($A$1:$A$13))=F$1))
```

I put `Up` and `Down` in a column and the numbers across the top.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: ,,,, it's nice one +  10 ☺